# Way to create different input and output sites for each user

Tags: file-management

I want to create a website where there is an input site that submits data to one **specific** output site which is only seen by that user. It would be optimal if those different sites would have different links.

The code for each site is exactly the same but the table the data is submitted to is different.

I don't want to manage and update about 70 files (keeps getting bigger of course) of each programming language but rather have just like now just one file.

There must be a way to do this, but I just can't come up with an answer. An example for a website that probably has to do this is prezi. For each user, they have to save the presentations they made. But how?

Comment: Many sites use the same URLs but with CGI variables and session cookies to personalize the pages.  The session ID + CGI variables tells the script code what user ID + document / object IDs to store the custom content under.  Look at Google Docs, Outlook web version, etc.  If there is a reason not to do this you might edit your question to include more details and examples of what your URLs would look like.

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much! As I looked for CGI variables, it seemed like they were used in perl? Are they also available for php?

Comment: If this is for real use, you also need to think about security.  For example if you have an URL like /editor/edit-page.php?document_id=123 then you need to make sure that the current login really does own document 123.  It is common for people to edit the URL and try using other ID numbers to see content they are not supposed to see like document 224 that belongs to a different user.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the terminology here. For "table" do you mean the table of the database or something else?
Plus, what do you mean for "different site"? Do you mean a different domain? Or just the path part of the address (I suppose it's this one).  
You will certainly have a tblUsers where the informations of all identified users are stored. You can save a table name there, a site name there, and use those in queries. You can also save special single session numbers that can be used directly in the url used for connecting to the site (that would be the optimal solution).